# Convert string to function but evaluate variable first

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Assume I do the following:

```js
  const
    externalVal = 'something',
    fn = () => {
      console.log(externalVal)
    })

  console.log(fn.toString())
```

The console log will stringify the function and specifically, `console.log(externalVal)` will be stringified.

Is there any way I can get the function block to convert to a string but contain the *value* of `externalVal` so it would come out like: `console.log('something')`?

The reason being is I can't access the pages window object via a browser extension content script, but I can inject a script into the document and run it - this doesn't help much unless I can pass in the value as well.

Just to clarify, I know I can access the the window object by injecting the script. That's the purpose of this question because I need to pass a value into that script and converting the function to a string isn't eval'ing the value of the variable.

Comment: But you **can** access `window` object of the page, see [this](/a/9517879) and [another example](/a/46870005).

Comment: @wOxxOm Well that's what I'm trying to do - insert a script into the page but for me, unless I can insert one of the values from my current context when the function is stringified it doesn't help

Comment: I doubt you will be able to do that. Time to figure out a different way of doing whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I doubt it too but thought it worth a question :)

Comment: That being said, I've just thought of a work around. I could pass in my function which uses DOM messaging between that and the content script to *ask* for the value.

Comment: If you run via textContent you can "pass" the arguments in the same string e.g. assuming fn = function(arg1, arg2) {} the code would be scriptElement.textContent = \`(${fn})(${JSON.stringify(['foo', 'bar']).slice(1, -1)})\`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Please add the answer and I'll give you some points ;)